# Is there any annotation for Gremlin Spring Boot for transactions?

Tags: java, transactions, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

Is there any @Transaction for  Gremlin in Spring Boot to handle commit and rollback?
Normal transaction handles dirty read?

Comment: Is this question about https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-gremlin? If so I see there is a note on that project that it has been deprecated. https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-gremlin

Comment: YES, but it's deprecated as you mentioned. If we have an active repo and It will be must easier for the development in spring boot.  If there is any plan to fork by Gremlin-community, please mention here. I would like to contribute.

Comment: Perhaps ask in either the TinkerPop Discord or on the Gremlin Users e-mail list. I am not aware of any such plans, but you may find other folks are interested.